# Using custom model name in lang files when translating

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So Let's say I have 2 models, in sub-directories

```
App\Models\AotherModelFolder\MyModel
App\Models\Custom\Test
```

Which I am storing in the database as the type of model the user performed an action on,

```
id | user_id | action | model_type | model_id
1  |  1      | deleted|  App\Models\AotherModelFolder\MyModel | 1
2  |  1      | updated|  App\Models\Custom\Test | 2
```

I want to dispay the acttion and the section they performed the action on, so let's say

```
{{ __("You :action on :model with an id of :id", [
    'action', $activity->action, 
    'model', $activity->model_type, 
    'id', $activity->model_id, 
]) }}
```

This will dispay as You deleted on App\Models\AotherModelFolder\MyModel with an id of 1

I am trying to not show the whole model, but rather replace that with let's say `My model`

I will have multiple, so can I play them all in an array and then pull the name from it? How can I achieve this?

Comment: should the name be always the same  e.g. `My model`, do you plan have laguage spesific names?

Answer (score 0):

I would create one language file according to your `fallback_locale` usually `en`,
`/resources/lang/en/models.json`and would do a list of all the Models and how they should be shortened:

```
{
    "App\Models\AotherModelFolder\MyModel": "My model"
}
```

If you want to have different names for different languages copy the file in the right folder an translate it.

Next I would edit/create a other file, each for each language you want to support, e.g.:
`/resources/lang/en/messages.json`

```
{
    "action_preformed": "You :action on :model with an id of :id"
}
```

If you have all you messages copy the same file in e.g. `/resources/lang/es/messages.json`
and translate the Text `"You :action on :model with an id of :id"`

now in your code you can use:

```
{{ __("messages.action_preformed", [
    'action' => $activity->action,
    'model' => trans('models.' . $activity->model_type),
    'id' => $activity->model_id,
]) }}
```

If you really want to translate the message than you should also translate `deleted`, `updated` , etc. in the same way

More about the topic : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization

Answer (score 0):

You may define a relationship "morph map" to instruct Eloquent to use a custom name for each model instead of the class name:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
    'posts' => 'App\Post',
    'videos' => 'App\Video',
]);
```

You may register the `morphMap` in the `boot` function of your `AppServiceProvider` or create a separate service provider if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Ok its simple, you want to log user actions on some models.

and you want to display only the name of the model.

example:
we have a user made changes on some model, lets say: App\User

the record will be:

```
action: delete
model: App\User
id: 43
```

to display just User you can do this:

```
$model = $model; // which is "App\User"
$modelName = class_basename(new $model()); // this will return User
```

## or better method:

you can define variable lets say: modelName in that model,

for App\User Model it will be

```
public $modelName = "User Model";
```

and you can do

```
$model = $model; // which is: "App\User"
$modelName = (new $model())->modelName;
```

## or another one :D

you can define a static var in the App\Model class

```
public static $modelName = "my User Model";
```

then you can call it like:

```
$model = $model;
$modelName = $model::$modelName;
```